# class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream sometimes returns null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, classloader

One of our application deployed on prod which has one of the script "downloadFileAsCsv-spark-1.scala" as part of jar.

Below code is called from constructor of an object which gets created frequently.

```
IOUtils.toString(XYZ.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("downloadFileAsCsv-spark-1.scala"))
```

Now it's been noticed that sometimes after couple of days run, above mentioned code starts throwing NullPointerException for same code path which was running previously in desired way as follows.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1906)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:778)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:759)
    at abc.XYZ.<init>(XYZ.java:99
```

However once NullPointer is received for once, this behavior in app remains consistent, until it's been restarted.

Any pointers what could be leading to above statement.

P.S. Since template is constant we can load same as one time in memory, but a bit curious to know what could lead above.

Comment: Have you checked the program's memory usage? With OpenJDK on Linux I experienced problems with memory leaks due to an ever-increasing table of temporary files created when accessing JAR resources. Although this eventuelly led to an OOM, not a NPE

Comment: @Cybran yes checked same, currently using oracle JDK 8, with xmx 6G and hardly 1G seems to be in use, though this instance in long run shows symptoms of high memory usage but not for this occurence.